# Newly started surges and thumping when I flush?

Tags: plumbing

We had a new home built, and for the past three years there has been no noises coming from the pipes when I flush the toilet in the upstairs bathroom. Now I flush and there comes three gushing sounds of running water and then a thumping sound. What would cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a clogged vent line.

"Gushing sounds of running water" is likely water being sucked out of traps, which would not happen if the vents were working as designed/built.

Thumping might be from air getting sucked in and then the remaining water going back to the traps, or pipe movement in reaction to the suction forces.

Time to check/clean out your vent lines.